# Rename file using regular expressions in .NET?

Tags: .net, regex

Is possible to write a regular expression, with the following file names as the input: 


4214690028_6.mp3
178146230886_001.waV
178146230886_999.Wav
178146230886_0001.mP3
NoUnderscore3088003.wav

where the string output is as follows:

6_4214690028.mp3
001_178146230886.waV
999_178146230886.Wav
0001_178146230886.mP3
NoUnderscore3088003.wav - Not touched

Just wondering if this is even feasible using nothing but the .NET Regex class..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you must use a regular expression it could be done.

```
String s = "4214690028_6.mp3";
String r = Regex.Replace(s, @"^(\d+)_(\d+)\.([^.]+)$", "$2_$1.$3");
Console.WriteLine(r); // => "6_4214690028.mp3"
```

[**Regex Explanation**](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl?re=%5E%28%5Cd%2B%29_%28%5Cd%2B%29%5C.%28%5B%5E.%5D%2B%29%24&.submit=Explain%21&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode)

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?)_(.*?)(?=\.)
```

Try this.Replace by `$2_$1`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/47